# How to remove 3 slashes in a row in a string with str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a script where I grab the body of an email and put that into a database. For whatever reason once in a while I will get an email wherein the string I have 3 slashes in a row within a sentence like so

```
$string = "You\\\'ll be great at that one day";
```

I am trying to figure out with `str_replace` how to remove the 3 slashes. If I do

```
str_replace("\\\","",$string)
```

of course, it doesn't work. How can I specifically target 3 slashes with `str_replace`?

**SOLVED**

With much messing around a simple `str_replace("\\\'", "'", $string)` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your input string.  If you want three *literal* backslashes in a PHP string, then you need *six* backslashes, because `\\` is a literal backslash.  Consider the following script:

```
$string = "You\\\\\\'ll be great at that one day";
echo $string . "\n";
echo str_replace("\\\\\\", "", $string);
```

This prints:

```
You\\\'ll be great at that one day
You'll be great at that one day
```

Note that you could also do a regex replacement with `preg_replace`, targeting exactly three backslashes:

```
echo preg_replace("/\\\\{3}/","",$string);
```

In regex terms, a single literal backslash is actually represented by four backslashes.

Comment: Even though it's a dupe it's a good answer...

Comment: @Nick Didn't know about that PHP duplicate.  For sure, I've seen this question before in Java though.